# How can I speed up this linq query on a List<> with search criteria on 3 attributes in the list object

Tags: c#, performance, linq, list

I have the following LINQ query.

There is a list of about 55 000 items. I need to do a search on **three** of the attributes within the items.

here is my code:

```
private List<Device> Devices = _db.Devices.ToList();

public Device TryFindDeviceInNetworks(ALL_Sims sim)
{
    var ips = new List<string>();
    if (sim.IP1 != null)
    {
        ips.Add(sim.IP1);
    }
    if (sim.IP2 != null)
    {
        ips.Add(sim.IP2);
    }

    var device =
        Devices.FirstOrDefault(
            x => ips.Contains(x.IPaddress1)
                 || ips.Contains(x.IPaddress2)
                 || ips.Contains(x.IPaddress3));

    return device;
}
```

Currently this operation takes some time.

I have a for loop going through about 100k items and in each iteration of it calls this function `TryFindDeviceInNetworks()`. It runs 8 - 10 hours plus on intel i5. Obviously this is single threaded.

My question is how can I speed this up? I have converted a few of my lists to dictionaries where I can in the application and this has helped drastically, however in this case I cant search on only one key?

Is there some sort of data structure which would be better suited than the `List<T>`?

The database is not located locally on on a LAN, so estimated ping of at least ~40ms + query time would be added to every iteration.

Comment: Is `ips` always a maximum of 2 entries in size, or is this a simplified example?

Comment: always 2 in my case. I just add then to a list, in order to do the contains in the linq query.

Comment: What type are the IPaddress properties? If it can do a 32-bit integer comparison (or 128-bit if they're IPv6), it's going to be a lot faster than a string comparison.

Comment: Looks like you're fetching all the rows from a database (`_db`?) and do a search in memory. You should make the query against DB instead.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek i think the downside to that is he's calling it 100k times - would be a lot of DB queries. I'd say in-memory is the better option in this case.

Comment: @itsme86 IPV4 and in my code it is a string in the format of `10.2.12.12` for example

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I have thought of this idea, as i could add a non clustered index on the 3 fields, however DB is on remote server on the internet, pins will be 40ms minimum per query?

Comment: Can you add code of the `for` loop you mentioned that calls this method?

Comment: What is your SQL table schema? Any RDBMS should be able to turn this into a trivial query.

Comment: one thing to remember, Dictionaries are way faster and more memory "friendly" than Lists, so if you can have a KVP, then use it.

Comment: Rather than creating a List for potentially 2 IPs, it would probably be faster just doing a straight comparison of each viable combination. Worth benchmarking anyway.

Comment: @Zapnologica You could most likely batch multiple invocations into one SQL query, to make the ping impact lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having one dictionary with all 3 IP Addresses you could have 3 dictionaries:

```
private List<Device> Devices = new List<Device>();

private Dictionary<string, Device> mapIP1;
private Dictionary<string, Device> mapIP2;
private Dictionary<string, Device> mapIP3;
```

You'd have to initialize them before doing the search:

```
public void InitializeDictionaries()
{
    mapIP1 = Devices.ToDictionary(x => x.IPaddress1);
    mapIP2 = Devices.ToDictionary(x => x.IPaddress2);
    mapIP3 = Devices.ToDictionary(x => x.IPaddress3);
}
```

The search itself can use `TryGetValue`:

```
public Device TryFindDeviceInNetworks(ALL_Sims sim)
{
    Device device = null;

    if (sim.IP1 != null)
    {
        if (mapIP1.TryGetValue(sim.IP1, out device))
            return device;
        if (mapIP2.TryGetValue(sim.IP1, out device))
            return device;
        if (mapIP3.TryGetValue(sim.IP1, out device))
            return device;
    }

    if (sim.IP2 != null)
    {
        if (mapIP1.TryGetValue(sim.IP2, out device))
            return device;
        if (mapIP2.TryGetValue(sim.IP2, out device))
            return device;
        if (mapIP3.TryGetValue(sim.IP2, out device))
            return device;
    }

    return device;
}
```

You'd have to be sure that there is no elements in `Devices` list that share the same address though, as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can't work with duplicate keys.

Comment: I think this can defiantly work, more memory intense, but that doesnt matter in my case. I want speed

Comment: One question. In the `InitializeDictionaries` function. how can I ignore items with a NULL value ?  Im getting a `A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` error. But it makes sense, because there are null values in the database.

Comment: This won´t work if two devices have same IP1 (IP2, or IP3). Also  the order of evaluation is different. the original code queries all IPs per device, while your code queries all devices per IP (or maybe I am already too tired)

Comment: @Zapnologica add `Where(x => x.IPaddressX != null)` before `ToDictionary` call.

Comment: You are a genius.  I must say I thought of doing a dictionary for each IP, but I had the idea of putting the device ID in the Value, and then I thought im still going to have to iterate through the list to find the device. but putting the device in the VALUE solves it all.,

Comment: I'm glad it works! Out of curiosity: what's the perf gain with that solution?

Comment: As said above, I have not bench marked it. And I doubt that was the only slow part of the program. But visually its around 50% faster.

Comment: Just some feedback,  My application is now using ~500Mb more memory. However I found another slow point, I was doing a dbcontect.add(device) in my other for loop which was extremely slow. So i added them to a temp list and then added the range to the dbcontext every 500. This sped up my program EXTREMELY. But this now leads me to believe the your mod has made extreme performance increase. I will compare one for one, when im not so pressed for time.

Answer (score 2):

```
var device =
    Devices.FirstOrDefault(
        x => ips.Contains(x.IPaddress1)
             || ips.Contains(x.IPaddress2)
             || ips.Contains(x.IPaddress3));
```

Is going to enumerate `ips` *three* times in the worst possible case (no matches). I would re-write it as:

```
var device =
    Devices.FirstOrDefault(
        x => ips.Any(y => y == x.IPaddress1
             || y == x.IPaddress2
             || y == x.IPaddress3);
```

So it only enumerates it once, checking each possible "match condition" as it goes and returning as soon as it finds one.

As some of the commenters have said, finding a way to do a simple number comparison will also be faster than a string comparison if it is possible.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? I believe this would help the OPs performance significantly

Comment: Iterating ips 3 times and doing 1/3 of the work on each iteration is doing to approximately the same as iterating it once and doing 3x the work per iteration; it's extremely unlikely that this would change a thing.  And of course, given that ips has so few items, both are going to be pretty darn tiny.

Comment: Just implemented this solution. It doesnt seem noticeably faster, but then again I haven't got any hard data to base it on besides a counter in the debug menu.

Comment: @Servy I thought I saw a comment that said it could be greater... looking now its gone/edited though, so I agree on that point. In my experience, reducing enumeration count tends to help, though you could very well be right in this instance.

Comment: Not enumerating an `IQueryable` that represents a database query, that represents a LINQ query that's doing expensive computation, or that represents a query that doesn't always yield the same values when iterated, is often very important.  None of those things are going on here.  If this were a general purpose method accepting any arbitrary `IEnumerable` (to which it would be possible to pass in a query doing one of the things mentioned about) then it would be important to only iterate it exactly one, just to ensure it actually works.  This isn't doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own loop instead of the linq and see how it performs:

Note: this code assumes you will always have 2 IP addresses in the ips collection, as stated in the comments on the question.

```
foreach(var device in Devices)
{
      if(device.IPaddress1 == ips[0] || device.IPaddress2 == ips[0] || device.IPaddress3 == ips[0] || device.IPaddress1 == ips[1] || device.IPaddress2 == ips[1] || device.IPaddress3 == ips[1] )
      return device;
}
```

This unrolls one of the loops and takes advantage of being able to return as soon as a match is found.

Further optimization can be performed by letting the database do the work instead.

Comment: Tried this, but obviously adds complexity for the cases where IP1 and IP2 are null as I don't add them to my `ips` list then?

Comment: foreach won´t be much faster than FirstOrDefault. It also returns as soon as first match is found and does not enumerate whole sequence. So your code is exactly the same what FirstOrDefault does

Answer (score 0):

Create lookups for each of your three keys.  It won't make much of a difference if you were only doing the search once, but if you're doing it a hundred thousand times, being able to lookup the values based on the IP in constant time will be a *huge* win:

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<FSKDevice> Devices = _db.Devices.ToList();
    private IList<ILookup<string, FSKDevice>> lookups;

    public Foo()
    {
        lookups = new[]{ 
            Devices.ToLookup(device => device.IPaddress1),
            Devices.ToLookup(device => device.IPaddress2),
            Devices.ToLookup(device => device.IPaddress3),
        };
    }

    public FSKDevice TryFindDeviceInNetworks(ALL_Sims sim)
    {
        var ips =  new[] { sim.IP1, sim.IP2 }
            .Where(ip => ip != null);

        return (from ip in ips
                from lookup in lookups
                let matches = lookup[ip]
                where matches.Any()
                select matches.First())
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```